# Multiple Unit Testing Projects -- Run all tests, but one project at a time

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, mstest

I have a large visual studio solution with 13 unit testing projects in it.  I want to run all the unit tests, but I want to ensure that they run one entire project at a time.  Is there anyway to achieve this?

Currently, when I select **Run All** from the `Test Explorer` window - I know that they run at what appears to be a semi-random order, where it might run a test from *Proj1* then *Proj2*, then come back to another test from *Proj1*.  The order in which they run is not an issue, the issue is that I only want a single project to execute then move on to the next project, etc...

Ideally, if a test from *Proj2* is the first unit test to execute it would run all unit tests in *Proj2* until there aren't anymore.  Then it would move on to the next unit test, if *Proj5* for example -- it would again run all of them within *Proj5* and then move on.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Please consider using Ordered Tests (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182631.aspx).

Comment: I looked at them but the order doesn't matter and seems like it would be a lot to manage.  My concern is jumping betwixt test projects during test execution...